# Give a tree where value of each node holds the sum of child nodes

Tags: haskell, tree

trying to figure out how to make a tree where the value of each node holds the sum of child nodes

```
data Tree a = LEAF a | NODE a  (Tree a)  (Tree a) 
              deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

addNode:: Num a => Tree a -> Tree a
addNode(NODE x (LEAF a) (LEAF b)) = (NODE (a+b)  (LEAF a) (LEAF b))
addNode(NODE x left right) = (NODE x (addNode(left)) (addNode(right)))

tree1 = NODE 1
     (NODE 2 (NODE 3 (LEAF 4) (LEAF 5)) (LEAF 6))
     (NODE 7 (LEAF 8) (LEAF 9))
```

When I run the code I got:

```
addNode tree1
NODE 1 (NODE 2 (NODE 9 (LEAF 4) (LEAF 5)) *** Exception: testTree.hs:(105,1)-(106,89) Non-exhaustive patterns in function addNode
```

Can't figure out what's the cause, any help is much appreciated

Comment: It's because recursion in your example eventually reaches `addNode (LEAF 4)` (etc), a case you haven't defined. You need a case for the `LEAF` constructor. (Btw, what is `createSumTree`? I assume this is supposed to be `addNode`. If it isn't my comment about recursion doesn't really make sense.)

Comment: Got you, thanks, was trying out with helper functions as well.

Comment: Always turn on warnings with `-Wall`, it reports errors like this.

Comment: There are at least two sensible meanings of "each node holds the sum of child nodes". One is to define `val (LEAF a) = a; val (NODE a _ _) = a` and then demand that this function return a tree such that wherever `NODE a l r` occurs, we have `a = val l + val r`. Another -- and different! -- meaning would be to demand that the tree returned have the same shape as the original, and at each position in the new tree, all of the values that are in the subtree rooted at that position in the original tree are summed. Is it one of these (or, perhaps, even a third meaning)?

Comment: I made an adjust into my answer, want to check it out?

Answer (score 2):

You where so close, you just need the base case, the `LEAF`:

```
data Tree a = LEAF a | NODE a  (Tree a)  (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

addNode:: Num a => Tree a -> Tree a
addNode (LEAF x) = LEAF x
addNode(NODE x left right) = NODE ((sumT left) + (sumT right)) (addNode left) (addNode right)

sumT :: Num a => Tree a -> a
sumT (LEAF a) = a
sumT (NODE _ left right) = (sumT left) + (sumT right)

t1 = NODE 1 t4 t3
t2 = NODE 3 (LEAF 4) (LEAF 5)
t3 = NODE 7 (LEAF 8) (LEAF 9)
t4 = NODE 2 t2 (LEAF 6)

NODE 1 (NODE 2 (NODE 3 (LEAF 4) (LEAF 5)) 
               (LEAF 6))
       (NODE 7 (LEAF 8) (LEAF 9))

$> addNode t1

NODE 32 (NODE 15 (NODE 9 (LEAF 4) (LEAF 5)) 
                 (LEAF 6))
        (NODE 17 (LEAF 8) (LEAF 9))
```

(In general function that work on a particular type - e.g. Tree - have to pattern match on every value constructor from that type or else Haskell will rise non-exhaustive pattern match error)

Answer (score 2):

We can generate a function that generates a 2-tuple where the first item is the sum of the tree, and the second item, the `Tree` itself:

```
addNode' :: Num a => Tree a -> (a, Tree a)
addNode' l@(LEAF x) = (x, l)
addNode' (NODE _ a b) = (sab, NODE sab ta tb)
    where (sa, ta) = addNode' a
          (sb, tb) = addNode' b
          sab = sa + sb
```

We thus should both take the `LEAF` and the `NODE` into account. Likely we need to calculate the sum recursively of the subtrees, and sum these up in the node, therefore it is more efficient to use a 2-tuple here, to store the result of the sum thus far.

then we can define an `addNode` function that unpacks the 2-tuple and returns only the last element:

```
addNode :: Num a => Tree a -> Tree a
addNode = snd . addNode'
```

This thus will produce a tree like:

```
Prelude> addNode tree1 
NODE 32 (NODE 15 (NODE 9 (LEAF 4) (LEAF 5)) (LEAF 6)) (NODE 17 (LEAF 8) (LEAF 9))
```

Comment: Right, I was only adding `LEAF` values rather sub `NODE` and `LEAF` at the same time. thanks.

Comment: Willem nice answer! after thinking a little bit, I manage to do the same with an aux function! You are my inspiration by the way :D